# Given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, what is the structure of its stalks $\mathcal{F}_x$?

Tags: sheaf-theory

Here is a quick question about definitions.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups of a space $M$. The stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$ at $x\in M$ is defined by
$$\mathcal{F}_x=\{(U,s):x\in U\subseteq M,U\text{ open },s\in\mathcal{F}(U)\}/\sim$$
where $(U,s)\sim(V,t)$ if there exists an open set $W$ such that $x\in W\subseteq U\cap V$ and $s|_W=t|_W$.

Now I am told that a homomorphism of sheaves $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ induces a homomorphism of stalks $\varphi_x:\mathcal{F}_x\to\mathcal{G}_x$. However, I was not given any group structure for a stalk.

> What is the group structure of the stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$?

My guess is that it is defined as
$$[(U,s)]+[(V,t)]=[(U\cap V,s|_{U\cap V}+t|_{U\cap V}].$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Right, that's the group structure [I think I've asked this question before also](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298353/canonical-group-structure-of-germs).

Comment: Pretty sure that's correct. Its the only reasonable choice, after all.